# File Reader - return the file?

Tags: javascript

Here's my file reader:

```
p.read = function(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {

        return e.target.result;
    }
}
```

But nothing is returned? Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried `fileReader.result`?

Comment: You *cannot* `return` anything from an asynchronous callback function. See also [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @Bergi I don't know how I didn't see that `return`. For some reason I thought they were printing the value and was having trouble with that

Comment: `return` returns from the function it's in. That return is nested in *another* function which will be executed at some point in the future. It has no impact on the outer function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you  cannot return it from a callback function

try to separate it in another function

I hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

This is an async function. That mean that if you do this :

```
p.read = function(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log('a');
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log('b');
        return e.target.result;
    }
}
```

and :

```
console.log('hello');
p.read('file');
console.log('c');
```

You will get

```
hello
c
a
b
```

Because javacript is asynchronous. Very nice b/c like so, your code is non-blocking:  it is really easy to do something while reading a big file.

In your example, you have to do :

```
p.read = function(file, callback) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    }
}
```

And to run:

```
p.read('file', function(content) {
   console.log(content);
});
```